# Plot values as unstacked bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot the following toy dataframe in R, specifically the True-True, False-True, True-False, and False-False combinations from columns B and C. These True and False values also correspond to 2 conditions ("X" or "Y").

```
A       B       C
X       True    True
Y       False   True
X       False   False
Y       True    True
Y       True    False
...     ...     ...
```

However, my current code (below) is stacking the values into 2 groups by condition. This current code also only gives me False-False, False-True, and True-True combinations. Somehow I've lost True-False.

I would like to plot the 4 combinations as 4 bars unstacked bars for condition X and another 4 unstacked bars for condition Y. Does anyone have advice on this?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = A, fill = interaction(B,C))) + 
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat="count")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `geom_bar(position="dodge2")` and they should arrange themselves side by side.

```
A <- c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y")
B <- c(T, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, T)
C <- c(T, T, F, T, F, F, F, T, F)

df <- data.frame(cbind(A, B, C))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=A, fill=interaction(B,C))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat="count")
```

I added some more data points so that you can see the different counts.

Example figure:

[image: example figure]

If you wanted to display the missing categories (e.g. the ones that don't have combinations of `interaction(B,C)` present), you could use the following:

```
A <- factor(c("X", "Y", "X", "Y", "Y", "X", "X", "Y", "Y"), levels=c("X", "Y"))
B <- factor(c(T, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, T), levels=c("FALSE", "TRUE"))
C <- factor(c(T, T, F, T, F, F, F, T, F), levels=c("FALSE", "TRUE"))

df <- data.frame(A, B, C)

df %>% group_by(A, B, C, .drop=F) %>% tally() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=A, y=n, fill=interaction(B,C), color=interaction(B,C))) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge2", stat="identity")
```

Example figure:

[image]